# Whitespace and code snippets in Slack Mobile

Tags: formatting, slack

I'm trying to post tables as code snippets using the Slack API; the tables are formatted like this (and looks this way on Desktop):

```
id id0 pct1   -16.5%  -16.7%
       num1     9308    4026
       num     -1538    -673
       pct00   88.8%   86.0%
```

But Slack Mobile does something weird with the whitespaces (it seems like it clips them past a certain length), which results in the table looking something like this on Slack Mobile:

```
id id0 pct1   -16.5% -16.7%
    num1   9308   4026
    num   -1538   -673
    pct00  88.8%   86.0%
```

Is there a certain character (including invisible characters) I could replace the whitespace with to maintain the spacing and readability? (Using say, an underscore or hyphen keeps the spacing but looks rather invasive.)

I don't know if there's a setting on the app that fixes this whitespace issue (if there is, it would solve my problem immediately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. Resolved it by using no-break space (U+00A0) which worked better with Slack on mobile. Hope that helps :-)

Comment: Exactly the solution I was looking for. (`'\xa0'` in Python.) Thanks!